# Detecting Port Utilized by Webbrowser

Tags: c#-3.0, browser, webbrowser-control

When the webbrowser control issues an HTTP request to a URL, it is assigned a port - which is utilized for the length of that connection.

Is there away to find out which port is being utilized for each connection the webbrowser control establishes/issues?

Comment: I doubt it's possible, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every request is potentially using a different port.  Since most requests are resolved in a couple of seconds and then closed, having the port information on the client isn't going to be very helpful.

If you're interested from a historical perspective, you can add the port number to the logs that many web servers generate.

In order to view this information live you can use a tool such as [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Now for the real question.  What are you trying to do?  There may be an easier way.

Comment: I am trying to get a historical view from the client perspective, not the server one.

TCPView could help, but the problem is that I need to build it in my application, not sure that is open source...

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting! I can imagine a few places where that kind of information might be useful.  (Ammunition for when the network wonks mess up the firewall rules <G>) The netstat command would probably be a better place to start than TCPView in this case.  I ran across this article that might be interesting http://poshcode.org/558

Answer (score 0):

you can run in background:

```
netstat -bn
```

and parse output to get information about your application (ports, ips, etc.)